# FOSUserBundle: resetting template not replacing %email%

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

The page displayed after clicking on `Reset password` button contains

> An email has been sent to %email%.

The `check_email.html.twig` template is overridden at `.../app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/view/Resetting` and contains

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
<p>
{{ 'resetting.check_email'|trans({'%tokenLifetime%': tokenLifetime})|nl2br }}
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

config.yml contains

```
    framework:
        translator:      ~
    ...
    fos_user:
        db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
        firewall_name: main
        user_class: 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        from_email:
            address:        admin@projectmana.org
            sender_name:    Application Support
        service:
            mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
        resetting:
            email:
                template: email/password_resetting.email.twig
```

`FOSUserBundle.en.yml` is in place at `.../app/Resources/translations`

FOSUserBundle installed is `dev-master 03ce036`.

Comment: Did you already create the file `app/Resources/views/email/password_resetting.email.twig`, since it is referenced?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Yes, that file exists and is used in the recipient's email.  Email is sent properly, it's just the lack of display (that should be like `@example.com`) that's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual solution was to require v2.0.0-beta1 in composer and/or get rid of the override of the translator file. A good clearing of cache helps, too.

Answer (score 0):

The page is not able to translate the `%email%` key since you have not specified it in the content of the `check_email` twig. Your template should contain something like: `{{ 'resetting.check_email'|trans({'%email%': email}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}`

Comment: Doing so results in `PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "Variable "email" does not exist in "FOSUserBundle:Resetting:check_email.html.twig"` per dev.log

Comment: Please try renaming the file to checkEmail.html.twig as this is how FOSUserBundle is naming it

Comment: Looking at [github/FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/views/Resetting) I see the file name as `check_email.html.twig`. Where does `checkEmail.html.twig` come from?

Comment: AHA! Following the "breadcrumbs" I learn that they've removed the `%email%` from `resetting.check_email` translation!!! So that's what I'll do too!  Just need to replace the translation file in my `.../app/Resources`

Comment: But there's more to do... Now `%tokenLifetime%` is not defined. Pain in the patootie.